# Assisted Service Module not running in Spartacus B2B with SAP Commerce cloud 2005/2011 (Hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

After installing the spartacus with SAP CC 2011 backend, when I have tried to open asm with URL

https://localhost:4200/powertools-spa/en/USD/?asm=true

and then login as asagent for a b2b customer ()

the request for the cart has user as 'undefined' in the url

> Request URL:
> https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/powertools-spa/users/**undefined**/carts?fields=carts(DEFAULT,potentialProductPromotions,appliedProductPromotions,potentialOrderPromotions,appliedOrderPromotions,entries(totalPrice(formattedValue),product(images(FULL),stock(FULL)),basePrice(formattedValue,value),updateable),totalPrice(formattedValue),totalItems,totalPriceWithTax(formattedValue),totalDiscounts(value,formattedValue),subTotal(formattedValue),deliveryItemsQuantity,deliveryCost(formattedValue),totalTax(formattedValue,%20value),pickupItemsQuantity,net,appliedVouchers,productDiscounts(formattedValue),saveTime,user,name)&lang=en&curr=USD

And the following error is displayed in the hybris logs

> ERROR [hybrisHTTP26] [RestHandlerExceptionResolver]
> de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.UnknownIdentifierException:
> Cannot find user with propertyValue '**undefined**'

Is there anything I am missing as part of setup?
And why do the users are going as undefined?

Answer (score 0):

*Update*: issue was caused by a user which didn't had `customerId` set.
Spartacus issue to follow this bug: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/10244

---

I tested the scenario you mentioned with basic spartacus (no customization) and the userId was never set to value of `undefined` and all requests to API contained correct userId.

Do you have any customizations on top of spartacus? In this case that we be mostly related either to auth services or to the `ActiveCartService`.

Comment: I have done the basic setup of spartacus 3.0 RC version and then did the settings to enable the smartedit.

Did you tried first log in to the asm with asagent and then used B2B customer credentials to start the session? for eg:- (powerdrillslovers) and after that tried to add something on the cart. ?

Comment: Customer Id is blank for the powerdrillslover@pronto-hw.com in backoffice, after setting the cutomer id (guid) in backoffice, it was able to add the items in the cart.

Comment: Good catch. I'll make sure the ASM emulation covers this case when customerId is not set for the user.